# DPY-4011: the database or network closed connection

Tags: python, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy, python-oracledb

I use flask 2.2.2, gunicorn 20.1.0, sqlalchemy 2.0.13 without Flask-SQLAlchemy and oracledb 1.3.1. I have two scemas and two engines each for their own schema because they need different users to access.
When I start app, and somebody makes request, sometimes i get error as on screenshot. How can i fix this problem?
[image]
I tried to find solution in google, all links said that is oracle driver problem, but i can`t understand how to fix it.

Comment: 1st you should check what has happened on DB server side. If your query triggers some internal database error, the DB will close TCP connection as session server dies.

Comment: @ibre5041 This error could raise or not on same sql query.

Comment: Please edit the text of the error as a code block in your question. It's best to [avoid posting an image of an exception](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: If you have a runnable example that fails, please open a python-oracledb issue on https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The problem is that sqlalchemy not thread/process safe. So i create app factory function and add engine.dispose(close=False) to this factory.